# GitHub ESLint action failing with "Permission Denied"

Tags: eslint, github-actions

I'm writing a CI workflow (GitHub actions), and it seems that eslint is failing with "Permission Denied" code 126. I can't seem to fix it.

Can someone explain why ESlint is failing with permission denied? If so, is there a solution?

[Here's a link to the pr where it's failing.](https://github.com/GeoFS-Autoland/autoland/pull/8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a GitHub action fails with `Permission Denied` there are two possibilities:

#### 1. You are trying to run a command that requires elevated privileges

To solve this just prefix `sudo`. E.g. `npx eslint` > `sudo npx eslint`. The [GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#administrative-privileges-of-github-hosted-runners) specify:

> The Linux and macOS virtual machines both run using passwordless sudo.

#### 2. A shell script does not have the *execute* filesystem permission set

If you have a unix/bash shell handy, you can change that with:

```
chmod +x ./.github/scripts/xxx.sh
```

If not, you can tell git to add the permission with this command:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x ./.github/scripts/xxx.sh
```

`update-index` is similar to `add` in that it adds the change to the index, so you'll have to commit and push as usual.